# Spring Boot Unit testing for Mock beans vs Mockito

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot

I am using a spring boot 1.5.4 project where I need a clarification on testing package.

I am seeing Spring Boot comes with `@MockBean` which is part of `org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito` package.

My question is - Is it similar to Mockito external dependency and I can avoid using Mockito as external dependency as spring boot mock.* package has all features which Mockito has?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already pointed in Greg's answer , mockito core is already included in `spring-boot-starter-test` so its already there in your project, no external dependency is needed.

Having said that - mockito's `@Mock` and Spring's `@MockBean` are a bit different in a way that `@MockBean` is basically a `@Mock` plus `@Bean` so it does what mockito annotation does plus it works with like a bean too i.e. it places instances in Spring's application context and all other spring bean related concepts come into picture too.

From [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html) -

> Annotation that can be used to add mocks to a Spring
>   ApplicationContext. Can be used as a class level annotation or on
>   fields in either @Configuration classes, or test classes that are
>   @RunWith the SpringRunner.
>
> Mocks can be registered by type or by bean name. Any existing single
>   bean of the same type defined in the context will be replaced by the
>   mock, if no existing bean is defined a new one will be added.
>
> When @MockBean is used on a field, as well as being registered in the
>   application context, the mock will also be injected into the field.

For non - Spring applications where DI & context are not there, you shoudl use `@Mock` and for Spring apps , you should use `@MockBean`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test/1.5.4.RELEASE) for spring-boot-starter-test, you'll see that it depends on the Mockito library so it is included for you.